# WYSIWYG-editor removes template partials/template variables

Tags: wygwam, wysiwyg, template-partials, ckeditor

I am using Wygwam as WYSIWYG-editor. Now when I add a template variable or template partial inside an html-tag in a field which uses Wygwam it will be removed when switching from source to visual.

That means I enter e.g. in the source-code something like

```
<a href="test1" {variable1}>test1</a>
<p>test{variable2}</p>
```

and after switching to Wysiwyg-layout the code changes to

```
<a href="test1">test1</a>
<p>test{variable2}</p>
```

Note that the variable outside the tag still is there (variable2), but the one inside the a-link is gone (variable1).

The "restrict allowed HTML"-setting is off, see image:

[image: CKEditor-config: Restrict allwed HTML is off]

Possibly the CKEditor-setting "extraAllowedContent" could help me, but I am not sure and do not understand how I could change this setting.

[image: CKEditor-setting: extraAllowedContent]

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Wyvern (an other wysiwyg) can "process" the ee variables and partials.
https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/wyvern

Comment: That would be neat. I checked documentation (https://docs.reinos.nl/wyvern/) and it lists Low Variables, at least.

Comment: Actually I talked to Rein (reinos.nl) and he assured me that Wyvern could process variables the way I intended. So this answer pushed me to the solution, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think template variables are supposed to be rendered inside WYGWAM to begin with. I just ran a test and the variable name `{tp_test}` was retained literally from Source to Preview, and then in an actual web page, as well.

EDIT: You can use https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/allow-ee-code to allow template code in fields.

So chasing if/when WYGWAM erases it is kind of a red herring. But yes the extraAllowedContent would fix that. e.g., I have "i[*]" to allow everything inside `<i>` tags (FontAwesome).

Comment: I tried this and entered a[*] into an extraAllowedContent-setting, but this did change nothing. Also I am not sure if the extraAllowedContent plays a role when you have set "restrict allowed html" to "no" as shown in my question.